# How to partially update an object from mongodb using FastAPI and pydantic? Making a patch request

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, fastapi, pydantic

I have to do a patch request to update partially an object in a mongodb collection with fastapi. I'm using the FARM (Fastapi, React, Mongodb) stack.

The object is like this:

```
 {"BranchOffice": "001",
  "BranchOfficeName": "Fortaleza",
  "Origin": "CO",
  "Screen": "pre-cadastro",
  "Holder": {
    "Name": "name",
    "Email": "titular@teste.com",
    "CellPhone": "99 99999-9999"
  }
```

there is more, but for example, only this part is enough.

I followed the documentation in this link about patch updates:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-updates/

The problem is that the update is done just in models without sub-models, e.g. "Holder" is a sub-model and the update fails, the fields are saved with "null' when  I send just a field. However the update happens when I send all the object, which is not the desired. To make the models I used Pydantic.

My route method to make the patch is that:

```
@router.patch("/shelf/{id}", response_model=DataFromShelf)
async def add_data_shelf(id: str, req: DataFromShelf = Body(...)):
    
       
    stored_data = await budget_collection.find_one({"_id": id})
    
   
    
    stored_item_model = DataFromShelf(**stored_data)
    
    update_data = req.dict(exclude_unset = True)
    

    updated_item = stored_item_model.copy(update=update_data)
    
    updated_item = jsonable_encoder(updated_item)
    
    updated_data = await budget_collection.update_one({"_id":id}, {"$set": updated_item})
    
    if updated_data:
        updated_data = await budget_collection.find_one({"_id": id})
        return updated_data
    return {"msg":"erro"}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It is unclear to me what the exact problem is. Your code looks fine for patching an object in MongoDB. Please provide an MRE (minimal reproducible example) so others can understand te problem and help you solve it.